# ExpressJS app generator not recognizing its flags

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I can't run the express app generator with flags.
See example below. I run `express --version` and it interpretes the --version part as a target directory and creates the app there. In Windows XP SP3.
Am I doing something wrong? My knowledge is really very limited.

```
X:\server>node --version
v0.8.6   

X:\server>express --version

   create : .
   create : ./package.json
   create : ./app.js
   create : ./public
   create : ./public/javascripts
   create : ./public/images
   create : ./public/stylesheets
   create : ./public/stylesheets/style.css
   create : ./routes
   create : ./routes/index.js
   create : ./routes/user.js
   create : ./views
   create : ./views/layout.jade
   create : ./views/index.jade 

   install dependencies:
     $ cd . && npm install

   run the app:
     $ node app

X:\server\--version>
```

Answer (score 0):

That same code works fine here in WinXP Windows Shell.  Is this in cygwin or the windows shell ?

Comment: Hi qbert, thanks for showing.  
It's the Windows shell where I installed a set of tools including node, mongo, ... to be able to work as in *NIX.  
All "portable" versions (except mongo).  
The setting of my environment is reported here: http://bit.ly/YbGYVg  
Actually, is quite a clean environment.